# JavascriptMVC – callback method not called

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, javascriptmvc

I tried to hook the Cookbook Tutorial to my rails3 backend.

**Problem:**
My backend service gets called and returns json. But for some rease JMVC doesnt invoke the callback method.

```
Cookbook.Models.Recipes.findAll({}, this.callback('list'));
```

I don't get **any errors and have no idea how to debug** this. So please help me.

Comment: can you post response from backend ? alongwith headers.

Comment: JavaScriptMVC's forum is very active.  If you ask questions there, you will get answers much more quickly.
First make sure you are getting a response from the server.  Also check the console, JMVC prints errors there.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the callback here. This should be something like this:

```
Cookbook.Models.Recipes.findAll({}, list);
```